# Mobile Safari like scrolling of UIWebView (with navigationbar stuck at top)

Tags: iphone, ios, browser, mobile-safari

How would I go about making a browser window that has the same scrolling properties as Mobile Safari? If you scroll Mobile Safari the `navigationbar` up top follows with it. If there is no more content it stops scrolling, and it has a very special way of zooming. Mobile Safari has it, and now even Opera mini for iPhone has it. Any ideas? I have tried hooking in to the `scrolldelegate` of the `UIWebView`, but that's not perfect at all. I'm out of ideas. How have the Opera Mini guys solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself but it seems to me that you could create a holder view that has your a view handling the navigation and the `UIWebView`, this would be tucked into a `UIScrollView` to facilitate the scrolling and then in the `UIScrollView` delegate pass the `UIWebView` as the view for zooming in `viewForZoomingInScrolView`.

Comment: From the UIWebView apple documentation: "Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled." So I'm not sure if it should work. I'm trying it out right now though,